# Having trouble with Subclasses in java

Tags: java, class, subclass

I was reviewing one of my textbook's questions and I am slightly confused. The code is:

```
public class BClass
{
  private int x;

  public void set(int a)
  {
    x=a;
  }

  public void print()
  {
    System.out.print(x);
  }
}

public class DClass extends BClass
  {
    private int y;


    public void set(int a, int b)
    {
      //Postcondition: x = a; y = b;
    }
```

The questions are:

a. Write the definition of the print method of DClass that overrides it.

b. Write the definition of the method set of the class DClass.

For a, would I be right in saying that putting the following in the subclass would be a successful override?

```
public void print()
{
  System.out.print(x + " and " + y);
}
```

I'm also having trouble with b. Because I'm given the postcondition, it's obvious that I should set y, the instance variable in the subclass, equal to b. The problem I'm facing is how to set x equal to a. Because the instance variable x belongs to the parent class, does that make it unable to be directly accessed? Or am I allowed to do this:

```
public void set(int a, int b)
{
  x = a;
  y = b;
}
```

Would really appreciate some help, Thanks!

Comment: Any time you want to override a method, annotate it with `@Override`.

Comment: A class inherits the accessible methods of its parent class.

Comment: Correct, you can't access `x` directly in the subclass because it's declared `private` in the parent.

Comment: I understand that the subclass inherits the accessible methods of its parent class. But is it possible for me to use the set method from the parent class inside the set method in the subclass?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking ... it's almost as if *you haven't tried it* ... your code as posted wouldn't compile because of access issues.

Comment: I was asking about using the superclasses' method inside the subclasses. I already got the answer from below that describes the super. to access the parent's methods. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: `public void set(int a, int b) { y = b; set(a); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is correct.  A is incorrect.  I was just looking to say that is how override works.  I didn't look at the validity of the method.

It should be

```
public void print() {
   super.print();
   System.out.print(" and " + y);
}
```

For B you need to invoke the super method so

```
public void set(int a, int b) {
   super.set(a);
   y = b;
}
```

Comment: A is also incorrect; you can't access `x` directly in the subclass.

Comment: Oh, this makes so much sense now.

So should i just take out the X for A? As long as its changed than that means its overridden, right?

Comment: No need for `super` here. It hasn't been overriden. The method could be made `final`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! Really cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is declared `private` in the base class. That means that in the derived class, you cannot access it to set it or to print it. However, the base class does have public methods to do both those things. Those methods *are* visible to the derived class, so you can/must use those.

In DClass.print, call the print method of the base class to print `x`:

```
public void print()
{
    super.print();
    System.out.print(" and " + y);
}
```

The [`super` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) is used to call the implementation of print in the parent class. Without `super.` in front of the call, it would call the same print method of the derived class, which would make the same call again, rapidly crashing with a stack overflow error.

In DClass.set, you likewise need to call the set method of the base class:

```
public void set(int a, int b)
{
    super.set(a);
    y = b;
}
```

Here, `super.` is optional in front of the `set` call, because the only method named `set` which takes exactly 1 argument is in the base class, and it is not overridden (only [overloaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)). However, including `super.` makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I didn't know about the super. Really helped!